# How to show icon with text message Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

i need to show icon on message box.  by using following code on alfresco. i can only show tile and content of msg box. please help me to show icon (?,!,...)

```
      Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(
      {
          title:"test",
          text: "warning"
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this enough?
In the appearance section in the share config you can add the following.

"Help Text 
A field can have help text to aid the user when filling in the form"

This has been quoted from the wiki https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms.

Answer (score 0):

There is predefined function icon in `Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt` you can use that to show icon on message box. This icon will display next to text.

[See here for more details](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-4.0.c/symbols/Alfresco.util.PopupManager.html#.displayPrompt)

i.e.

```
 Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(
      {
          title:"test",
          text: "warning",
          icon: "/images/confirmicon.png"
      });
```